# Maven use local dependency and got NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/Synchronization

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror

I wrote a simple mvc framework named symphony-mvc, and run maven install to put the jar into the local maven repository. But when i use it in a web project, i got this error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/Synchronization
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2267)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1244)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at xyz.imwyy.symphony.util.ClassUtil.loadClass(ClassUtil.java:41)
at xyz.imwyy.symphony.util.ClassUtil.doAddClass(ClassUtil.java:124)
at xyz.imwyy.symphony.util.ClassUtil.getClassSet(ClassUtil.java:75)
at xyz.imwyy.symphony.helper.ClassHelper.<clinit>(ClassHelper.java:20)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at xyz.imwyy.symphony.util.ClassUtil.loadClass(ClassUtil.java:41)
at xyz.imwyy.symphony.SymphonyLoader.init(SymphonyLoader.java:27)
at xyz.imwyy.symphony.DispatcherServlet.init(DispatcherServlet.java:40)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4920)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
```

In the symphony-mvc framework, i use `ClassUtil` to load class, but all the class that need to load got `NoClassDefFoundError`. I have not used jta, Why tell me `NoClassDefFoundError:javax/transaction/Synchronization`? By the way, I have put the jar into `WEB-INF/lib`.

Here is the `pom.xml` in symphony-mvc

```
<groupId>xyz.imwyy</groupId>
<artifactId>symphony-mvc</artifactId>
<version>3.3</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--SLF4J-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Mysql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jackson json-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Apache Commons Lang-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Apache Commons Collections-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Apache Commons DbUtils-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Apache DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Here is the `pom.xml` in the web project

```
<groupId>xyz.imwyy</groupId>
<artifactId>symphony-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xyz.imwyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>symphony-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `WEB-INFO/lib` is a typo posting here? The dir is called `WEB-INF`

Comment: yes. `WEB-INF`. I misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

You did not add all the dependency jars.

There are 3 ways to solve it:

- Manually adding jars - add all the jars symphony-mvc is based on
- Manually add the jar , but create a jar containing all dependencies (look at shade plugin for example)
- In your project add a maven dependency in your symphony-mvc , this will automatically also get all the needed jars **(recommended way**)

Comment: I have added maven dependency in symphony-mvc(see my pom.xml), but still not work.

Comment: You use provided jars in your project - add the same provided in your main project as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a jar to your dependencies that contains the missing class (`javax/transaction/Synchronization`). This class is not necessarily directly called in your code, but indirectly by some framework you use.

Comment: Yes. I have figured it out. The `org.slf4j` use `javax/transaction/Synchronization`, and i replace  `org.slf4j` with a higher version and it works!